# Using ImageResizer with FileResult, ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, imageresizer

We have the following Controller for getting file:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
public class FileController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public FileResult Index(long id)
    {
        if (id <= 0) return null;
        Attachment attachment = Service.GetAttachmentById(id);
        if (attachment == null) return null;
        new Task(() => Service.IncreaseAttachmentViewCount(id)).Start();
        string filename = attachment.Name;
        //"application/octet-stream";
        string mimeType = System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename);
        return File(attachment.Path, mimeType);
    }
}
```

It's OK and works well but it doesn't work with [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/releases/3-4-2) API
e.g: 
The following image shows in natural size(1920*1200) and maxwidth or maxheight doesn't work at all. But if I use the absolute file path it works.

```
<img src="File/Index/1231?maxwidth=300&maxheight=300" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serving large binary files via an application framework of any kind (whether MVC, WebAPI, Rails, WebForms, or HttpHandlers) is generally a bad idea.

The [ImageResizer Best Practices guide](http://imageresizing.net/docs/best-practices) explains in more detail.

To get good performance, you should implement this as a URL rewrite (or IVirtualImageProvider) instead.

Handle ImageResizer's `Config.Current.Pipeline.Rewrite` event, and parse the path yourself. Modify the Path based on the ID you parsed, and increment your view counter.  This should require 5-8 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm new in ImageResizer, Could you please post a link for handling Config.Current.Pipeline.Rewrite event